# spoolsv.exe error when printing to shared printer (Windows 7 -> Windows XP home)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printer, print-spooler

I have an HP Photosmart C5383 installed on a Windows XP Home PC. I got a notebook with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, to upgrade my older Vista Home Premium 32-bit machine. I have shared this printer and been able to print successfully on the Vista machine, but when I try print on the Windows 7 machine, the spoolsv.exe service generates a C++ error and basically causes the Windows XP machine (the server) to hang until the service/process is stopped and restarted. The machines are obviously on a workgroup, good old MSHOME.

HP's support has no answers, and I cannot seem to find any solutions via a Google search.

All drivers are up to date and the Windows 7 machine detects the printer just fine, I even get a custom device stage when viewing the device on the notebook. But I can't print anything, and the spool service is crashing no matter what.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/xp-to-windows-7-printer-sharing/

I created a local port, instead of relying on the network version that was automatically created. That worked. I didn't know I could do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me just changing the name to a shorter one worked!